# How to mock .Cast<IType> with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I want to mock the following code snippet (`myObject`) with NSubstitute:

```
foreach (IType foo in myObject.CustomCollection
                        .Cast<IType>()
                        .Where(bar => <predicate>))
                { ... }
```

Here is the sub configuration:

```
IMyObject subMyObject = Substitute.For<IMyObject>();
ICustomCollection subCollection = Substitute.For<ICustomCollection>();
ITravelDailyCalculation subCollectionItem1 = Substitute.For<IType>();
ITravelDailyCalculation subCollectionItem2 = Substitute.For<IType>();
var list = new List<IType>
{
    subCollectionItem1,
    subCollectionItem2
};
subCollection.Cast<ITravelDailyCalculation>().Returns(list);
subMyObject.CustomCollection.Returns(subCollection);
```

The line `subCollection.Cast<ITravelDailyCalculation>().Returns(list);` throws the following exception:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException :
> Could not find a call to return from.
>
> Make sure you called Returns() after calling your substitute (for
> example: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(value)), and that you are not
> configuring other substitutes within Returns() (for example, avoid
> this: mySub.SomeMethod().Returns(ConfigOtherSub())).
>
> If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that
> the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member. Return
> values cannot be configured for non-virtual/non-abstract members.

The exception also occurs if I leave `list` empty. Is there a way to get this sub config work?

Comment: Trying to mock a `Cast<T>` is weird thing to do. If that is supported by `ICustomCollection` it should work with out you having to mock it... I think. We'll need to see your code

Comment: don't mock `Cast`, but just provide some meaningfull collection... Otherwise you'll end up mocking `Where` as well, which is painful.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the option to use a different collection

Comment: Trying to mock LINQ (which is effectively what you end up doing) is basically a non-starter, since extension methods cannot be mocked, and presumably the custom collection does not have any implementation of LINQ itself, so this call always goes to `Enumerable.Cast` and not to any mockable method. Mock `CustomCollection` with a concrete object itself. As long as the objects inside that collection can be cast to `IType`, the code will work. (Technically mocking the `IEnumerable` implementation is also an option, but that's almost never more appropriate or convenient.)